# Getting Conflicts while using Rich faces with eclipse

Tags: richfaces

I created a web dynamic project in eclipse and i have choose the JSF version is 2.0. and i added Rich faces jars . list of jars are richfaces-api-3.3.4.Final,richfaces-impl-3.3.4.Final,richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.4.Final,richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final. when i try to execute the project the rich faces are not working. means which i wrote use rich faces tag that line code will not executing..
please can u suggest me any other process will i follow or i need to any extra jars...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The *impl* packages are conflicting. Use only `richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.4.Final` if you're using JSF 2.0

Comment: What ajax? The `f:ajax` component? That's not supported.

Comment: <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}">
            <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="out" />
            </h:inputText>

Comment: above i added an ajax action with rich faces tag.. its not working

Comment: `<a4j:ajax>` is a RF 4 component, RF 3 has `<a4j:support>`

Comment: i removed RF3.x jars and Added RF 4.0.